# Using PS and TTY

Tags: shell, terminal, process, ps

[image]

I execute on a different shell 'sleep 600'. I open a different terminal and I executed 'ps' to see my current process , however , I dint see any sleep process. I don't know why i couldn't see it and  Why is that , different terminals contained different PID and PTS if the command is the same on both (ps) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from `man ps`:

```
By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID
(euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal
as the invoker.
```

To see all your processes, you'll need something like `ps -ef | grep <userid>`.